# Can "there" refer to "case"?

Tags: word-usage

Can one say something like "This seems to be valid in the general case, but is not proven *there*"? Or must one say "then"?

Comment: There will be some contexts where you could use ***then / now*** in this type of construction, but even then it would probably be better to stick to ***there / here***, which are probably *always* acceptable. Though to be honest I'm not sure whether that preceding sentence would be better with ***even there*** rather than ***even then***.

Comment: Can you tell some more about the context where this sentence would appear? Is it referring to mathematics?

Comment: Yes. Why? Something with the word "proven"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There** refers to a [location](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/there).  I believe in this case, the "location" would be within whatever "the general case" refers to.  If you were to replace "there" with "in that general case", it should mean the same thing.

> This seems to be valid in the general case, but is not proven **in that general case**.

Same meaning, yes? Because you can replace "there" with a location, it follows that "there" is the proper word to use.

Comment: It is not always  used for locations. 1.3In that respect; on that issue:
I don’t agree with you there. Check here http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/there

Comment: @Sina I guess that's what I meant by location. My bad. A broad sense of placement, I suppose. "In that respect" refers to something that came previously. In this case, I assumed that location referred to a placement (which, in my mind, included things that come previously).